# Excluir linha de tabela através de uma ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

Na minha tabela as linhas são inseridas através do JavaScript com um ID que é o mesmo ID preenchido no formulário, e essas linhas incluem um icone de lixeira que capturei como `let botaoExcluir = document.querySelector(".material-icons")`

Minha duvida é a seguinte: tenho como identificar o ID da linha onde o ícone foi clicado e excluir a linha em questão? também se souberem outra forma de fazer isso também sou todo ouvidos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue os códigos em HTML, CSS e JS para testes

```js
let botaoInserirPessoa = document.querySelector("#inserirPessoa");
let tabela = document.querySelector("#cadastrosPessoa")

let campoId = document.querySelector("#id")
let campoNome = document.querySelector("#nome")
let campoCpf = document.querySelector("#cpf")
let campoRg =document.querySelector("#rg")
let campoNascimento = document.querySelector("#dataNascimento")
let campoSexo = document.querySelector("#sexo")

let botaoExcluir = document.querySelector(".material-icons")

let bancoDeCadastros = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nome": "Francisca Julia da Costa",
      "cpf": "457.696.936-65",
      "rg": "47.360.897-2",
      "data_nasc": "23/03/1944",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nome": "Noah Felipe Silva",
      "cpf": "956.531.431-70",
      "rg": "40.974.782-8",
      "data_nasc": "11/07/1964",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nome": "Alícia Rosângela Melo",
      "cpf": "066.291.353-18",
      "rg": "36.214.141-1",
      "data_nasc": "18/02/1978",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "nome": "Cristiane Renata Ana das Neves",
      "cpf": "946.074.401-08",
      "rg": "32.301.736-8",
      "data_nasc": "10/05/1966",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "nome": "Priscila Benedita Vanessa Ferreira",
      "cpf": "888.282.394-68",
      "rg": "44.524.670-4",
      "data_nasc": "15/11/1966",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "nome": "Bianca Carolina Nunes",
      "cpf": "484.323.140-13",
      "rg": "44.466.563-8",
      "data_nasc": "16/03/1948",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "nome": "Yuri Vicente Manuel Silveira",
      "cpf": "250.111.093-56",
      "rg": "18.597.361-9",
      "data_nasc": "05/09/1974",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "nome": "Melissa Alessandra Barros",
      "cpf": "446.675.916-25",
      "rg": "25.598.673-7",
      "data_nasc": "13/01/2000",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "nome": "Márcia Daniela Lara da Cruz",
      "cpf": "932.803.826-02",
      "rg": "40.653.176-6",
      "data_nasc": "04/06/1986",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "nome": "Filipe Anderson Rafael Assis",
      "cpf": "704.869.005-41",
      "rg": "39.383.334-3",
      "data_nasc": "19/11/1995",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "nome": "Luís Vinicius Sebastião Jesus",
      "cpf": "035.960.588-56",
      "rg": "29.915.692-8",
      "data_nasc": "23/04/1965",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "nome": "Cecília Caroline Nascimento",
      "cpf": "034.396.672-78",
      "rg": "48.673.066-9",
      "data_nasc": "04/02/1951",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "nome": "Raimunda Sandra Ferreira",
      "cpf": "757.187.891-85",
      "rg": "21.189.806-5",
      "data_nasc": "17/11/1974",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "nome": "Andreia Isabelly Juliana Melo",
      "cpf": "736.348.985-85",
      "rg": "24.677.018-1",
      "data_nasc": "11/10/1963",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "nome": "Nicolas Bernardo Moura",
      "cpf": "061.370.865-26",
      "rg": "16.302.343-8",
      "data_nasc": "08/06/1989",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "nome": "Diego Benjamin Tiago da Luz",
      "cpf": "991.152.443-42",
      "rg": "38.315.100-4",
      "data_nasc": "04/06/1990",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "nome": "Marlene Emanuelly Yasmin Cavalcanti",
      "cpf": "781.233.625-52",
      "rg": "21.068.742-3",
      "data_nasc": "15/10/1961",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "nome": "Vanessa Isabela da Luz",
      "cpf": "872.138.490-85",
      "rg": "44.289.193-3",
      "data_nasc": "05/09/1982",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "nome": "Camila Flávia Vera Mendes",
      "cpf": "790.524.518-77",
      "rg": "40.847.994-2",
      "data_nasc": "01/07/1952",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "nome": "Luana Lívia Lara Campos",
      "cpf": "532.901.056-01",
      "rg": "14.732.946-2",
      "data_nasc": "19/08/1981",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "nome": "Josefa Nina Galvão",
      "cpf": "379.743.833-80",
      "rg": "13.878.690-2",
      "data_nasc": "27/01/1943",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "nome": "Natália Isabelly Silvana da Paz",
      "cpf": "454.172.867-29",
      "rg": "22.986.096-5",
      "data_nasc": "17/09/1980",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "nome": "Amanda Sebastiana Vieira",
      "cpf": "703.941.038-90",
      "rg": "50.251.196-5",
      "data_nasc": "08/06/1960",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "nome": "Noah Pedro Alves",
      "cpf": "074.733.106-58",
      "rg": "32.110.015-3",
      "data_nasc": "14/08/1992",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "nome": "Giovana Camila da Conceição",
      "cpf": "418.746.840-49",
      "rg": "35.520.215-3",
      "data_nasc": "25/06/1947",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 26,
      "nome": "Pietro Joaquim Emanuel Gonçalves",
      "cpf": "003.502.230-25",
      "rg": "12.099.068-4",
      "data_nasc": "21/04/1999",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 27,
      "nome": "Tereza Kamilly Mariana Porto",
      "cpf": "050.946.705-90",
      "rg": "39.830.941-3",
      "data_nasc": "16/06/1959",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "nome": "Caroline Emanuelly Lívia Moreira",
      "cpf": "673.831.546-57",
      "rg": "24.561.727-9",
      "data_nasc": "09/04/1948",
      "sexo": "Feminino"
    },
    {
      "id": 29,
      "nome": "Gabriel Ricardo da Paz",
      "cpf": "829.270.172-98",
      "rg": "30.407.114-6",
      "data_nasc": "24/03/1980",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "nome": "Giovanni Igor Augusto Pires",
      "cpf": "584.880.490-72",
      "rg": "33.874.271-2",
      "data_nasc": "24/08/1946",
      "sexo": "Masculino"
    }
  ]

let renderCadastros = banco =>{
    
    for (let i=0; i<bancoDeCadastros.length; i++){    
        
        let novaTabela = `<tr id="${banco[i].id}">  
                            <td>${banco[i].id}</td>
                            <td>${banco[i].nome}</td>
                            <td>${banco[i].cpf}</td>
                            <td>${banco[i].rg}</td>
                            <td>${banco[i].data_nasc}</td>
                            <td>${banco[i].sexo}</td>
                            <td class="material-icons">delete_forever</td>
                        </tr>`
                        
        tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela
    }
}

botaoInserirPessoa.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    
    let id = campoId.value
    let nome = campoNome.value
    let cpf = campoCpf.value
    let rg = campoRg.value
    let nascimento = campoNascimento.value
    let sexo = campoSexo.value

    let novaTabela = `<tr id="${id}">  
                        <td>${id}</td>
                        <td>${nome}</td>
                        <td>${cpf}</td>
                        <td>${rg}</td>
                        <td>${nascimento}</td>
                        <td>${sexo}</td>
                        <td class="material-icons">delete_forever</td>
                    </tr>`          
    
    //Limpa os campos do formulário                
    campoId.value = ""
    campoNome.value = ""
    campoCpf.value = ""
    campoRg.value = ""
    campoNascimento.value = "" 
    campoSexo.value = ""
    
    //Inclui os novos dados na tabela
    tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela

    //Atualiza o banco de cadatros
    let novoCadastro = {
        "id": id,
        "nome": nome,
        "cpf": cpf,
        "rg": rg,
        "data_nasc": nascimento,
        "sexo": sexo
    }

    bancoDeCadastros.push(novoCadastro)
})

renderCadastros(bancoDeCadastros)
```

```css
/*Root*/
*{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

/*Container principal*/
#container{
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 15px;
}

/*Campos do formulário*/
#inserirDados div, input, button{
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 3px;
}

#inserirDados input{
    width: 120px;
}

#inserirDados button{
    width: 60px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    
    color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    background-color: rgb(38, 98, 230);

    transition: .3s;
}
#inserirDados button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(42, 89, 190);
    transition: .3s;
}

/*Tabela*/
#cadastrosPessoa{
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}

#cadastrosPessoa th{
    border: 0;
}

#cadastrosPessoa td{
    border: 1px solid  rgb(77, 226, 122);
    font-weight: normal;

    padding: 3px;
}

#cadastrosPessoa .material-icons{
    cursor:pointer;
    
    transition: .3s;
}

#cadastrosPessoa .material-icons:hover{
    
    color: tomato;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Listagem de pessoas</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="container">
        <div id="inserirDados">
            <h1>Adicionar colaborador</h1>
            <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="ID">
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">
            <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF">
            <input type="text" name="rg" id="rg" placeholder="RG">
            <input type="text" name="dataNascimento" id="dataNascimento" placeholder="Nascimento">
            <input type="text" name="sexo" id="sexo" placeholder="Sexo">
            <br>
            <button id="inserirPessoa">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <table id="cadastrosPessoa">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>CPF</th>
            <th>RG</th>
            <th>Nascimento</th>
            <th>Sexo</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
        
</body>

<script src="/scripts.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
rel="stylesheet">

</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Ub7.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Ub7.png)

Comment: Acho que a lógica aí seria ao clicar no excluir: remover o registro do banco e recriar a tabela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternativo a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486891/95771), você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, já que o `id` da sua `<tr>` e única, pode associar o mesmo `id` da sua `<tr>` a um atributo que podemos chamar de `data-id` no seu `.material-icons`, no loop `for` onde você cria as `<tr>`:

```js
let renderCadastros = (banco) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < bancoDeCadastros.length; i++) {
    let novaTabela = `<tr id="${banco[i].id}">
                        <td>${banco[i].id}</td>
                        <td>${banco[i].nome}</td>
                        <td>${banco[i].cpf}</td>
                        <td>${banco[i].rg}</td>
                        <td>${banco[i].data_nasc}</td>
                        <td>${banco[i].sexo}</td>
                        <td class="material-icons" data-id="${banco[i].id}">delete_forever</td>
                    </tr>`;
                        // adicionando data-id="${banco[i].id} para o elemento

    tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela;
  }
};
```

Agora vamos reescrever o:

```js
let botaoExcluir = document.querySelector(".material-icons")
```

para:

```js
let botaoExcluir = document.querySelectorAll('.material-icons');
```

Para selecionar todos os elementos que irão fazer a exclusão e adicionar um evento de `click` para cada um deles. Para isso, vamos fazer um loop `forEach`, pois `querySelectorAll` retorna um array, e adicionar o `addEventListener` para cada um:

```js
botaoExcluir.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    ...
  });
});
```

E agora, vamos capturar o `data-id` de cada um desses elementos para a partir desse `data-id`, vamos remover a `<tr>` do documento, já que `data-id` e igual ao `id` da `<tr>`:

```js
botaoExcluir.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const idLinha = el.getAttribute('data-id'); // pegamos o valor 'data-id'

    console.log(document.getElementById(`${idLinha}`)); // neste log vai mostrar o
                                                        // <tr> com id igual a 'data-id'

    document.getElementById(`${idLinha}`).remove(); // selecionamos o elemento com valor
                                                    // do id igual ao valor de data-id
                                                    // e o removeremos do documento.
  });
});
```

Para tudo funcionar corretamente, todo o código acima deve ser adicionado depois da funcão `renderCadastros(bancoDeCadastros)`, pois os elementos tem que ser renderizados no documento antes de serem capturados. Vou criar uma funcao chamada de `addEventToMaterialIcons` que vai conter toda a logica e vamos executa-la em seguida:

```js
renderCadastros(bancoDeCadastros);

function addEventToMaterialIcons() {
  let botaoExcluir = document.querySelectorAll('.material-icons');

  botaoExcluir.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const idLinha = el.getAttribute('data-id');

      console.log(document.getElementById(`${idLinha}`));
      document.getElementById(`${idLinha}`).remove();
    });
  });
}
```

Agora pra resolver o problema que voce mencionou no comentario, vamos alterar um pouco a logica que cria uma nova linha na tabela. Vamos so adicionar a chamada para a funcao `addEventToMaterialIcons` dentro, para evitar repeticao de codigo:

```js
botaoInserirPessoa.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let id = campoId.value;
  let nome = campoNome.value;
  let cpf = campoCpf.value;
  let rg = campoRg.value;
  let nascimento = campoNascimento.value;
  let sexo = campoSexo.value;

  let novaTabela = `<tr id="${id}">
                <td>${id}</td>
                <td>${nome}</td>
                <td>${cpf}</td>
                <td>${rg}</td>
                <td>${nascimento}</td>
                <td>${sexo}</td>
                <td class="material-icons" data-id="${id}">delete_forever</td>
            </tr>`;

  //Limpa os campos do formulário
  campoId.value = '';
  campoNome.value = '';
  campoCpf.value = '';
  campoRg.value = '';
  campoNascimento.value = '';
  campoSexo.value = '';

  //Inclui os novos dados na tabela
  tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela;

  //Atualiza o banco de cadatros
  let novoCadastro = {
    id: id,
    nome: nome,
    cpf: cpf,
    rg: rg,
    data_nasc: nascimento,
    sexo: sexo,
  };

  addEventToMaterialIcons();

  bancoDeCadastros.push(novoCadastro);
});
```

Como um novo elemento foi adicionado, vamos atribuir um evento de clique para ele, por isso invocamos `addEventToMaterialIcons`.

Codigo final:

```js
  let botaoInserirPessoa = document.querySelector('#inserirPessoa');
  let tabela = document.querySelector('#cadastrosPessoa');

  let campoId = document.querySelector('#id');
  let campoNome = document.querySelector('#nome');
  let campoCpf = document.querySelector('#cpf');
  let campoRg = document.querySelector('#rg');
  let campoNascimento = document.querySelector('#dataNascimento');
  let campoSexo = document.querySelector('#sexo');

  let bancoDeCadastros = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'Francisca Julia da Costa',
      cpf: '457.696.936-65',
      rg: '47.360.897-2',
      data_nasc: '23/03/1944',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nome: 'Noah Felipe Silva',
      cpf: '956.531.431-70',
      rg: '40.974.782-8',
      data_nasc: '11/07/1964',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      nome: 'Alícia Rosângela Melo',
      cpf: '066.291.353-18',
      rg: '36.214.141-1',
      data_nasc: '18/02/1978',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      nome: 'Cristiane Renata Ana das Neves',
      cpf: '946.074.401-08',
      rg: '32.301.736-8',
      data_nasc: '10/05/1966',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      nome: 'Priscila Benedita Vanessa Ferreira',
      cpf: '888.282.394-68',
      rg: '44.524.670-4',
      data_nasc: '15/11/1966',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      nome: 'Bianca Carolina Nunes',
      cpf: '484.323.140-13',
      rg: '44.466.563-8',
      data_nasc: '16/03/1948',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      nome: 'Yuri Vicente Manuel Silveira',
      cpf: '250.111.093-56',
      rg: '18.597.361-9',
      data_nasc: '05/09/1974',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      nome: 'Melissa Alessandra Barros',
      cpf: '446.675.916-25',
      rg: '25.598.673-7',
      data_nasc: '13/01/2000',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      nome: 'Márcia Daniela Lara da Cruz',
      cpf: '932.803.826-02',
      rg: '40.653.176-6',
      data_nasc: '04/06/1986',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      nome: 'Filipe Anderson Rafael Assis',
      cpf: '704.869.005-41',
      rg: '39.383.334-3',
      data_nasc: '19/11/1995',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      nome: 'Luís Vinicius Sebastião Jesus',
      cpf: '035.960.588-56',
      rg: '29.915.692-8',
      data_nasc: '23/04/1965',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      nome: 'Cecília Caroline Nascimento',
      cpf: '034.396.672-78',
      rg: '48.673.066-9',
      data_nasc: '04/02/1951',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      nome: 'Raimunda Sandra Ferreira',
      cpf: '757.187.891-85',
      rg: '21.189.806-5',
      data_nasc: '17/11/1974',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      nome: 'Andreia Isabelly Juliana Melo',
      cpf: '736.348.985-85',
      rg: '24.677.018-1',
      data_nasc: '11/10/1963',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      nome: 'Nicolas Bernardo Moura',
      cpf: '061.370.865-26',
      rg: '16.302.343-8',
      data_nasc: '08/06/1989',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 16,
      nome: 'Diego Benjamin Tiago da Luz',
      cpf: '991.152.443-42',
      rg: '38.315.100-4',
      data_nasc: '04/06/1990',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 17,
      nome: 'Marlene Emanuelly Yasmin Cavalcanti',
      cpf: '781.233.625-52',
      rg: '21.068.742-3',
      data_nasc: '15/10/1961',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 18,
      nome: 'Vanessa Isabela da Luz',
      cpf: '872.138.490-85',
      rg: '44.289.193-3',
      data_nasc: '05/09/1982',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 19,
      nome: 'Camila Flávia Vera Mendes',
      cpf: '790.524.518-77',
      rg: '40.847.994-2',
      data_nasc: '01/07/1952',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 20,
      nome: 'Luana Lívia Lara Campos',
      cpf: '532.901.056-01',
      rg: '14.732.946-2',
      data_nasc: '19/08/1981',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 21,
      nome: 'Josefa Nina Galvão',
      cpf: '379.743.833-80',
      rg: '13.878.690-2',
      data_nasc: '27/01/1943',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 22,
      nome: 'Natália Isabelly Silvana da Paz',
      cpf: '454.172.867-29',
      rg: '22.986.096-5',
      data_nasc: '17/09/1980',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 23,
      nome: 'Amanda Sebastiana Vieira',
      cpf: '703.941.038-90',
      rg: '50.251.196-5',
      data_nasc: '08/06/1960',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 24,
      nome: 'Noah Pedro Alves',
      cpf: '074.733.106-58',
      rg: '32.110.015-3',
      data_nasc: '14/08/1992',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 25,
      nome: 'Giovana Camila da Conceição',
      cpf: '418.746.840-49',
      rg: '35.520.215-3',
      data_nasc: '25/06/1947',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 26,
      nome: 'Pietro Joaquim Emanuel Gonçalves',
      cpf: '003.502.230-25',
      rg: '12.099.068-4',
      data_nasc: '21/04/1999',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 27,
      nome: 'Tereza Kamilly Mariana Porto',
      cpf: '050.946.705-90',
      rg: '39.830.941-3',
      data_nasc: '16/06/1959',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 28,
      nome: 'Caroline Emanuelly Lívia Moreira',
      cpf: '673.831.546-57',
      rg: '24.561.727-9',
      data_nasc: '09/04/1948',
      sexo: 'Feminino',
    },
    {
      id: 29,
      nome: 'Gabriel Ricardo da Paz',
      cpf: '829.270.172-98',
      rg: '30.407.114-6',
      data_nasc: '24/03/1980',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
      id: 30,
      nome: 'Giovanni Igor Augusto Pires',
      cpf: '584.880.490-72',
      rg: '33.874.271-2',
      data_nasc: '24/08/1946',
      sexo: 'Masculino',
    },
  ];

  let renderCadastros = (banco) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < bancoDeCadastros.length; i++) {
      let novaTabela = `<tr id="${banco[i].id}">
                  <td>${banco[i].id}</td>
                  <td>${banco[i].nome}</td>
                  <td>${banco[i].cpf}</td>
                  <td>${banco[i].rg}</td>
                  <td>${banco[i].data_nasc}</td>
                  <td>${banco[i].sexo}</td>
                  <td class="material-icons" data-id="${banco[i].id}">delete_forever</td>
              </tr>`;

      tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela;
    }
  };

  botaoInserirPessoa.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let id = campoId.value;
    let nome = campoNome.value;
    let cpf = campoCpf.value;
    let rg = campoRg.value;
    let nascimento = campoNascimento.value;
    let sexo = campoSexo.value;

    let novaTabela = `<tr id="${id}">
              <td>${id}</td>
              <td>${nome}</td>
              <td>${cpf}</td>
              <td>${rg}</td>
              <td>${nascimento}</td>
              <td>${sexo}</td>
              <td class="material-icons" data-id="${id}">delete_forever</td>
          </tr>`;

    //Limpa os campos do formulário
    campoId.value = '';
    campoNome.value = '';
    campoCpf.value = '';
    campoRg.value = '';
    campoNascimento.value = '';
    campoSexo.value = '';

    //Inclui os novos dados na tabela
    tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela;

    //Atualiza o banco de cadatros
    let novoCadastro = {
      id: id,
      nome: nome,
      cpf: cpf,
      rg: rg,
      data_nasc: nascimento,
      sexo: sexo,
    };
    
    addEventToMaterialIcons();
    
    bancoDeCadastros.push(novoCadastro);
  });

  renderCadastros(bancoDeCadastros);

  function addEventToMaterialIcons() {
    let botaoExcluir = document.querySelectorAll('.material-icons');

    botaoExcluir.forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const idLinha = el.getAttribute('data-id');

        document.getElementById(`${idLinha}`).remove();
      });
    });
  }

  addEventToMaterialIcons();
```

```css
* {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Roboto;
        color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
      }

      /*Container principal*/
      #container {
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 15px;
      }

      /*Campos do formulário*/
      #inserirDados div,
      input,
      button {
        margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
        padding: 3px;
      }

      #inserirDados input {
        width: 120px;
      }

      #inserirDados button {
        width: 60px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 8px;

        color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
        background-color: rgb(38, 98, 230);

        transition: 0.3s;
      }
      #inserirDados button:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: rgb(42, 89, 190);
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      /*Tabela*/
      #cadastrosPessoa {
        margin: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: left;
      }

      #cadastrosPessoa th {
        border: 0;
      }

      #cadastrosPessoa td {
        border: 1px solid rgb(77, 226, 122);
        font-weight: normal;

        padding: 3px;
      }

      #cadastrosPessoa .material-icons {
        cursor: pointer;

        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      #cadastrosPessoa .material-icons:hover {
        color: tomato;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Listagem de pessoas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="inserirDados">
        <h1>Adicionar colaborador</h1>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="ID" />
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF" />
        <input type="text" name="rg" id="rg" placeholder="RG" />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="dataNascimento"
          id="dataNascimento"
          placeholder="Nascimento"
        />
        <input type="text" name="sexo" id="sexo" placeholder="Sexo" />
        <br />
        <button id="inserirPessoa">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table id="cadastrosPessoa">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>CPF</th>
        <th>RG</th>
        <th>Nascimento</th>
        <th>Sexo</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
</html>
```

O que difere da outra resposta, além da lógica, é o fato de o evento de clique está relacionado somente o elemento de classe `.material-icons` e não ao documento todo. Obviamente, esta é mais uma solução dentre muitas possíveis, assim como a outra resposta.

Comment: Olá, a ajuda de vocês foi de grande ajuda! @Cmte Cardeal eu optei por fazer meu código do estilo que você mandou, já que sua ideia era a mesma que a minha inicialmente, porém eu não consegui colocar ela em pratica. Porém, tenho um problema quanto ao código que é na hora que eu insiro um novo cadastro. ao fazer isso, a ação de excluir não funciona mais, você saberia o que pode ser?

Comment: @DiegoSousa Entendi, mas e facil de resolver. Fiz uma atualizacao da minha resposta. Veja se serve pra voce.

Comment: perfeito, corrigido e funcionando como esperado. Uma duvida apenas, porque a criação do botão capturando o material icons não pode ser feita fora da função? apenas funciona se dentro dela.

Comment: Porque voce criou um novo elemento da tabela e quando isso acontece, voce chama uma funcao aqui: `botaoInserirPessoa.addEventListener('click, () => {...})` e somente o que esta dentro desta funcao sera executado, entao para adicionar um evento para o `material icons`, voce tem que chamar `addEventToMaterialIcons` para atualizar os eventos para todos os botoes de excluir, incluindo os novos que sao adicionados pelo fomulario.

Comment: Muito obrigado, foi de excelente ajuda!!! @Cmte Cardeal

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendaria um `addEventListener` de `click` no documento inteiro, ao clicar ele vai pegar o atributo class do elemento clicado com um `target` e `getAttribute()`, se for `material-icons`, ele vai pegar `id` do elemento pai dele, utilizando o `parentNode`(que é a linha) e, ou seja utilizando o `parentNode.id` ele vai pegar o `id` do elemento pai, e com um `remove()` ele remove o elemento.

```js
    let botaoInserirPessoa = document.querySelector("#inserirPessoa");
    let tabela = document.querySelector("#cadastrosPessoa")

    let campoId = document.querySelector("#id")
    let campoNome = document.querySelector("#nome")
    let campoCpf = document.querySelector("#cpf")
    let campoRg =document.querySelector("#rg")
    let campoNascimento = document.querySelector("#dataNascimento")
    let campoSexo = document.querySelector("#sexo")

    let botaoExcluir = document.querySelector(".material-icons")

    let bancoDeCadastros = [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "nome": "Francisca Julia da Costa",
          "cpf": "457.696.936-65",
          "rg": "47.360.897-2",
          "data_nasc": "23/03/1944",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "nome": "Noah Felipe Silva",
          "cpf": "956.531.431-70",
          "rg": "40.974.782-8",
          "data_nasc": "11/07/1964",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "nome": "Alícia Rosângela Melo",
          "cpf": "066.291.353-18",
          "rg": "36.214.141-1",
          "data_nasc": "18/02/1978",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "nome": "Cristiane Renata Ana das Neves",
          "cpf": "946.074.401-08",
          "rg": "32.301.736-8",
          "data_nasc": "10/05/1966",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "nome": "Priscila Benedita Vanessa Ferreira",
          "cpf": "888.282.394-68",
          "rg": "44.524.670-4",
          "data_nasc": "15/11/1966",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "nome": "Bianca Carolina Nunes",
          "cpf": "484.323.140-13",
          "rg": "44.466.563-8",
          "data_nasc": "16/03/1948",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "nome": "Yuri Vicente Manuel Silveira",
          "cpf": "250.111.093-56",
          "rg": "18.597.361-9",
          "data_nasc": "05/09/1974",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "nome": "Melissa Alessandra Barros",
          "cpf": "446.675.916-25",
          "rg": "25.598.673-7",
          "data_nasc": "13/01/2000",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "nome": "Márcia Daniela Lara da Cruz",
          "cpf": "932.803.826-02",
          "rg": "40.653.176-6",
          "data_nasc": "04/06/1986",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "nome": "Filipe Anderson Rafael Assis",
          "cpf": "704.869.005-41",
          "rg": "39.383.334-3",
          "data_nasc": "19/11/1995",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "nome": "Luís Vinicius Sebastião Jesus",
          "cpf": "035.960.588-56",
          "rg": "29.915.692-8",
          "data_nasc": "23/04/1965",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "nome": "Cecília Caroline Nascimento",
          "cpf": "034.396.672-78",
          "rg": "48.673.066-9",
          "data_nasc": "04/02/1951",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "nome": "Raimunda Sandra Ferreira",
          "cpf": "757.187.891-85",
          "rg": "21.189.806-5",
          "data_nasc": "17/11/1974",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "nome": "Andreia Isabelly Juliana Melo",
          "cpf": "736.348.985-85",
          "rg": "24.677.018-1",
          "data_nasc": "11/10/1963",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 15,
          "nome": "Nicolas Bernardo Moura",
          "cpf": "061.370.865-26",
          "rg": "16.302.343-8",
          "data_nasc": "08/06/1989",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 16,
          "nome": "Diego Benjamin Tiago da Luz",
          "cpf": "991.152.443-42",
          "rg": "38.315.100-4",
          "data_nasc": "04/06/1990",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 17,
          "nome": "Marlene Emanuelly Yasmin Cavalcanti",
          "cpf": "781.233.625-52",
          "rg": "21.068.742-3",
          "data_nasc": "15/10/1961",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 18,
          "nome": "Vanessa Isabela da Luz",
          "cpf": "872.138.490-85",
          "rg": "44.289.193-3",
          "data_nasc": "05/09/1982",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 19,
          "nome": "Camila Flávia Vera Mendes",
          "cpf": "790.524.518-77",
          "rg": "40.847.994-2",
          "data_nasc": "01/07/1952",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 20,
          "nome": "Luana Lívia Lara Campos",
          "cpf": "532.901.056-01",
          "rg": "14.732.946-2",
          "data_nasc": "19/08/1981",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "nome": "Josefa Nina Galvão",
          "cpf": "379.743.833-80",
          "rg": "13.878.690-2",
          "data_nasc": "27/01/1943",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 22,
          "nome": "Natália Isabelly Silvana da Paz",
          "cpf": "454.172.867-29",
          "rg": "22.986.096-5",
          "data_nasc": "17/09/1980",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 23,
          "nome": "Amanda Sebastiana Vieira",
          "cpf": "703.941.038-90",
          "rg": "50.251.196-5",
          "data_nasc": "08/06/1960",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 24,
          "nome": "Noah Pedro Alves",
          "cpf": "074.733.106-58",
          "rg": "32.110.015-3",
          "data_nasc": "14/08/1992",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 25,
          "nome": "Giovana Camila da Conceição",
          "cpf": "418.746.840-49",
          "rg": "35.520.215-3",
          "data_nasc": "25/06/1947",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 26,
          "nome": "Pietro Joaquim Emanuel Gonçalves",
          "cpf": "003.502.230-25",
          "rg": "12.099.068-4",
          "data_nasc": "21/04/1999",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 27,
          "nome": "Tereza Kamilly Mariana Porto",
          "cpf": "050.946.705-90",
          "rg": "39.830.941-3",
          "data_nasc": "16/06/1959",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 28,
          "nome": "Caroline Emanuelly Lívia Moreira",
          "cpf": "673.831.546-57",
          "rg": "24.561.727-9",
          "data_nasc": "09/04/1948",
          "sexo": "Feminino"
        },
        {
          "id": 29,
          "nome": "Gabriel Ricardo da Paz",
          "cpf": "829.270.172-98",
          "rg": "30.407.114-6",
          "data_nasc": "24/03/1980",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        },
        {
          "id": 30,
          "nome": "Giovanni Igor Augusto Pires",
          "cpf": "584.880.490-72",
          "rg": "33.874.271-2",
          "data_nasc": "24/08/1946",
          "sexo": "Masculino"
        }
      ]

    let renderCadastros = banco =>{
        
        for (let i=0; i<bancoDeCadastros.length; i++){    
            
            let novaTabela = `<tr id="${banco[i].id}">  
                                <td>${banco[i].id}</td>
                                <td>${banco[i].nome}</td>
                                <td>${banco[i].cpf}</td>
                                <td>${banco[i].rg}</td>
                                <td>${banco[i].data_nasc}</td>
                                <td>${banco[i].sexo}</td>
                                <td class="material-icons">delete_forever</td>
                            </tr>`
                            
            tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela
        }
    }

    botaoInserirPessoa.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        
        let id = campoId.value
        let nome = campoNome.value
        let cpf = campoCpf.value
        let rg = campoRg.value
        let nascimento = campoNascimento.value
        let sexo = campoSexo.value

        let novaTabela = `<tr id="${id}">  
                            <td>${id}</td>
                            <td>${nome}</td>
                            <td>${cpf}</td>
                            <td>${rg}</td>
                            <td>${nascimento}</td>
                            <td>${sexo}</td>
                            <td class="material-icons">delete_forever</td>
                        </tr>`          
        
        //Limpa os campos do formulário                
        campoId.value = ""
        campoNome.value = ""
        campoCpf.value = ""
        campoRg.value = ""
        campoNascimento.value = "" 
        campoSexo.value = ""
        
        //Inclui os novos dados na tabela
        tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela

        //Atualiza o banco de cadatros
        let novoCadastro = {
            "id": id,
            "nome": nome,
            "cpf": cpf,
            "rg": rg,
            "data_nasc": nascimento,
            "sexo": sexo
        }

        bancoDeCadastros.push(novoCadastro)
    })

    renderCadastros(bancoDeCadastros)

    document.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
       if (e.target.getAttribute('class') == 'material-icons'){
       alert(e.target.parentNode.id)
       document.getElementById(e.target.parentNode.id).remove()
    
    }

})
```

```css
    /*Root*/
    *{
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Roboto;
        color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    }

    /*Container principal*/
    #container{
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 15px;
    }

    /*Campos do formulário*/
    #inserirDados div, input, button{
        margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    #inserirDados input{
        width: 120px;
    }

    #inserirDados button{
        width: 60px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 8px;
        
        color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
        background-color: rgb(38, 98, 230);

        transition: .3s;
    }
    #inserirDados button:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: rgb(42, 89, 190);
        transition: .3s;
    }

    /*Tabela*/
    #cadastrosPessoa{
        margin: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #cadastrosPessoa th{
        border: 0;
    }

    #cadastrosPessoa td{
        border: 1px solid  rgb(77, 226, 122);
        font-weight: normal;

        padding: 3px;
    }

    #cadastrosPessoa .material-icons{
        cursor:pointer;
        
        transition: .3s;
    }

    #cadastrosPessoa .material-icons:hover{
        
        color: tomato;
        transition: .3s;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Listagem de pessoas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="container">
            <div id="inserirDados">
                <h1>Adicionar colaborador</h1>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="ID">
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">
                <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF">
                <input type="text" name="rg" id="rg" placeholder="RG">
                <input type="text" name="dataNascimento" id="dataNascimento" placeholder="Nascimento">
                <input type="text" name="sexo" id="sexo" placeholder="Sexo">
                <br>
                <button id="inserirPessoa">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        <table id="cadastrosPessoa">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>CPF</th>
                <th>RG</th>
                <th>Nascimento</th>
                <th>Sexo</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
            
    </body>

    <script src="/scripts.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet">

    </html>
```

Código adicioado:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
    if (e.target.getAttribute('class') == 'material-icons'){
        alert(e.target.parentNode.id)
        document.getElementById(e.target.parentNode.id).remove()
}
})
```

Pode fazer com umas variáveis tambem se achar melhor:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
    if (e.target.getAttribute('class') == 'material-icons'){
        alert(e.target.parentNode.id)
        var linha = document.getElementById(e.target.parentNode.id)
        linha.remove()
}
})
```

PS: Coloquei um `alert` só para mostrar o `id` e confirmar se está funcionando
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: muito obrigado!